# From SharePoint Content Database, Using SQL-Server Query how to fetch the 'Document GUID' based on 'Content Type'

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to get all the documents based on content type using SQL Server Query. I aware that, querying the content database without using API is not advisable, but still i want to perform this action in Java Application through SQL Server Query. Can someone assist ?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not advisable.  Consider using the [REST Search API](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2013/04/09/how-to-query-sharepoint-2013-using-rest-and-javascript.aspx).  This will return the data in XML or JSON format and you can easily tailor the query to get the exact type of documents you are interested in by content type.  Keep in mind your documents may be in multiple content databases.